# How to create data channel in WebRTC peer connection?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I'm trying to learn how to create an `RTCPeerConnection` so that I can use the `DataChannel` API. Here's what I have tried from what I understood:

```
var client = new mozRTCPeerConnection;
var server = new mozRTCPeerConnection;

client.createOffer(function (description) {
    client.setLocalDescription(description);
    server.setRemoteDescription(description);

    server.createAnswer(function (description) {
        server.setLocalDescription(description);
        client.setRemoteDescription(description);

        var clientChannel = client.createDataChannel("chat");
        var serverChannel = server.createDataChannel("chat");

        clientChannel.onmessage = serverChannel.onmessage = onmessage;

        clientChannel.send("Hello Server!");
        serverChannel.send("Hello Client!");

        function onmessage(event) {
            alert(event.data);
        }
    });
});
```

I'm not sure what's going wrong, but I'm assuming that the connection is never established because no messages are being displayed.

Where do I learn more about this? I've already read the [Getting Started with WebRTC - HTML5 Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/) tutorial.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I finally got it to work after sifting through a lot of articles: http://jsfiddle.net/LcQzV/

First we create the peer connections:

```
var media = {};
media.fake = media.audio = true;
var client = new mozRTCPeerConnection;
var server = new mozRTCPeerConnection;
```

When the client connects to the server it must open a data channel:

```
client.onconnection = function () {
    var channel = client.createDataChannel("chat", {});

    channel.onmessage = function (event) {
        alert("Server: " + event.data);
    };

    channel.onopen = function () {
        channel.send("Hello Server!");
    };
};
```

When the client creates a data channel the server may respond:

```
server.ondatachannel = function (channel) {
    channel.onmessage = function (event) {
        alert("Client: " + event.data);
    };

    channel.onopen = function () {
        channel.send("Hello Client!");
    };
};
```

We need to add a fake audio stream to the client and the server to establish a connection:

```
navigator.mozGetUserMedia(media, callback, errback);

function callback(fakeAudio) {
    server.addStream(fakeAudio);
    client.addStream(fakeAudio);
    client.createOffer(offer);
}

function errback(error) {
    alert(error);
}
```

The client creates an offer:

```
function offer(description) {
    client.setLocalDescription(description, function () {
        server.setRemoteDescription(description, function () {
            server.createAnswer(answer);
        });
    });
}
```

The server accepts the offer and establishes a connection:

```
function answer(description) {
    server.setLocalDescription(description, function () {
        client.setRemoteDescription(description, function () {
            var port1 = Date.now();
            var port2 = port1 + 1;

            client.connectDataConnection(port1, port2);
            server.connectDataConnection(port2, port1);
        });
    });
}
```

Phew. That took a while to understand.

Comment: Why wee need to create fake audio stream if I want to create data channel only to transfer data  between peers?

Comment: Couple of issues:  1) Fake audio is no longer required (and hasn't been for a long while now 2) setLocalDescription() and setRemoteDescription() both MUST have success *and* error callbacks supplied per the spec.  Chrome and FF have been lenient on this (though we have a regression in FF32 that breaks the leniency; it may be fixed in 32.1 or if not in 33), but it is in violation of the spec.  3) connectionDataConnection() is no required or used now; that was an old temporary thing in FF

Answer (score 4):

I've [posted a gist](https://gist.github.com/natevw/5045693) that shows setting up a data connection, compatible with *both* Chrome and Firefox.

The main difference is that where in FF you have to wait until the connection is set up, in Chrome it's just the opposite: it seems you need to create the data connection *before* any offers are sent back/forth:

```
var pc1 = new RTCPeerConnection(cfg, con);
if (!pc1.connectDataConnection) setupDC1();    // Chrome...Firefox defers per other answer
```

The other difference is that Chrome passes an event object to `.ondatachannel` whereas FF passes just a raw channel:

```
pc2.ondatachannel = function (e) {
    var datachannel = e.channel || e;
```

Note that you currently need Chrome Nightly started with `--enable-data-channels` for it to work as well.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a sequence of events I have working today (Feb 2014) in Chrome.  This is for a simplified case where peer 1 will stream video to peer 2.

1. Set up some way for the peers to exchange messages.  (The variance in how people accomplish this is what makes different WebRTC code samples so incommensurable, sadly.  But mentally, and in your code organization, try to separate this logic out from the rest.)
2. On each side, set up message handlers for the important signalling messages.  You can set them up and leave them up.  There are 3 core messages to handle & send:

   - an ice candidate sent from the other side ==> call `addIceCandidate` with it
   - an offer message ==> `SetRemoteDescription` with it, then make an answer & send it
   - an answer message ===> `SetRemoteDescription` with it
3. On each side, create a new peerconnection object and attach event handlers to it for important events: onicecandidate, onremovestream, onaddstream, etc.

   - ice candidate ===> send it to other side
   - stream added ===> attach it to a video element so you can see it
4. When both peers are present and all the handlers are in place, peer 1 gets a trigger message of some kind to start video capture (using the `getUserMedia` call)
5. Once `getUserMedia` succeeds, we have a stream.  Call `addStream` on the peer 1's peer connection object.
6. Then -- and only then -- peer 1 makes an offer
7. Due to the handlers we set up in step 2, peer 2 gets this and sends an answer
8. Concurrently with this (and somewhat obscurely), the peer connection object starts producing ice candidates.  They get sent back and forth between the two peers and handled (steps 2 & 3 above)
9. Streaming starts by itself, opaquely, as a result of 2 conditions:

   - offer/answer exchange
   - ice candidates received, exchanged, and added

I haven't found a way to add video after step 9.  When I want to change something, I go back to step 3.

Comment: While your answer doesn't provide code, i feel that it is by far the best. It took me a few weeks to understand how to successfully connect two WebRTC clients, and this answer is spot on. Code is nice, but next comes the question of whether you want to use ajax or websockets - node.js, Java, or php, etc. One could use this answer to do it any way they'd like.