# How looks WebRTC peer negotiation workflow?

Tags: webrtc

I need to develop a custom WebRTC peer (I need to establish audio or/and data connection between web-browser and non-browser). I however, struggle to find a proper, clear description of the handshake phase.

Answers to questions such as [How to create data channel in WebRTC peer connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134090/how-is-a-webrtc-peer-connection-established) are not entirely helpful, as they are not too detailed. Specifically, they say nothing about SDP contents.

Can anyone explain this or recommend any good documentation?

Comment: Are you referring to signaling?

Comment: Yes. I understand that it's my role to build a channel to initially deliver offer/answers to peers but I can't find detailed instructions how these messages should be built.

Comment: Start from ICE: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5245 - it also covers basic moments on SDP. Basically, you need to start from ICE and STUN/TURN, then continue with SDP. At that stage your app would be able to exchange with SDP packets and pass signaling stage. After that you will need implement DTLS protocol support for your client. And then SRTP/SCTP.

Answer (score 12):

[Here is a page with some graphs showing how the signaling process works](http://www.webrtc.org/native-code/native-apis). Basically, you set some client side stuff first:

- PeerConnectionFactory; to generate PeerConnections,
- PeerConnection; one for every connection to another peer you want (usually 1),
- MediaStream; to hook up the audio and video from your client device.

Then you generate an `SDP` `offer`

```
peerConnection.createOffer();
```

on the caller side and send it to the callee. The callee sets this `offer`

```
peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(insert-the-offer-here);
```

and generates an `SDP` `answer`

```
peerConnection.createAnswer();
```

and sends it back to the caller. The caller receives this `answer` and sets it.

```
peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(insert-the-answer-here);
```

Both the caller and callee get a call to

```
onAddStream() {...} //needs to be implemented in your code
```

The callee when the caller's `offer` is set and the caller when the callee's `answer` is set. This callback signals the beginning of the connection.
You can also use `ICE` (`STUN`/`TURN`) to avoid `firewall` and `NAT` issues, but this is optional. Although in production code, you probably want to implement it anyway.

Note: Webrtc documentation is scarce and subject to change, take everything you read about webrtc (at least anything written as of now) with a grain of salt...